# Extracting data from a invoice PDF to my datasource using azure/cognitiveservices-computervision

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am building a demo application for reading an invoice pdf using the OCR library provided by Microsoft for NodeJS. The data are extracting well but I got stuck in one point. In the invoice pdf doc the amount, quantity is in tabular format. So I am not getting any relation regarding which value is for the amount and which value is for quantity. I am attaching my PDF file and extract text for reference. Please let me know if there is any way to extract those data.

[image: INVImaeg]

```
{
 "page": 1,
 "angle": 0,
 "width": 8.2639,
 "height": 11.6806,
 "unit": "inch",
 "lines": [
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.6679,0.7621,1.4191,0.7621,1.4191,0.8842,0.6679,0.8842],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "TestSam1",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.6679,0.7621,1.4191,0.7621,1.4191,0.8842,0.6679,0.8842],
     "text": "TestSam1",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.6677,0.992,1.2962,0.992,1.2962,1.1002,0.6677,1.1002],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "West Bengal",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.6677,1.0014,0.9218,1.0014,0.9218,1.0807,0.6677,1.0807],
     "text": "West",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.959,0.992,1.2962,0.992,1.2962,1.1002,0.959,1.1002],
     "text": "Bengal",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [5.9831,0.9355,7.7952,0.9355,7.7952,1.1598,5.9831,1.1598],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "TAX INVOICE",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [5.9831,0.9407,6.5404,0.9407,6.5404,1.1556,5.9831,1.1556],
     "text": "TAX",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [6.6434,0.9355,7.7952,0.9355,7.7952,1.1598,6.6434,1.1598],
     "text": "INVOICE",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.6741,1.1359,0.9013,1.1359,0.9013,1.2246,0.6741,1.2246],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "India",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.6741,1.1359,0.9013,1.1359,0.9013,1.2246,0.6741,1.2246],
     "text": "India",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.6179,1.3359,0.6811,1.3359,0.6811,1.4139,0.6179,1.4139],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "#",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.6179,1.3359,0.6811,1.3359,0.6811,1.4139,0.6179,1.4139],
     "text": "#",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.334,3.0461,1.334,3.0461,1.4153,2.3861,1.4153],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": ": INV-000772",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.3546,2.4067,1.3546,2.4067,1.4152,2.3861,1.4152],
     "text": ":",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [2.4456,1.334,3.0461,1.334,3.0461,1.4153,2.4456,1.4153],
     "text": "INV-000772",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.622,1.4831,1.2323,1.4831,1.2323,1.5673,0.622,1.5673],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "Invoice Date",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [0.622,1.4831,0.963,1.4831,0.963,1.5673,0.622,1.5673],
     "text": "Invoice",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [1.0041,1.4872,1.2323,1.4872,1.2323,1.5672,1.0041,1.5672],
     "text": "Date",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.4777,3.0196,1.4777,3.0196,1.5864,2.3861,1.5864],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": ": 28/08/2021",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.5067,2.4067,1.5067,2.4067,1.5673,2.3861,1.5673],
     "text": ":",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [2.4406,1.4777,3.0196,1.4777,3.0196,1.5864,2.4406,1.5864],
     "text": "28/08/2021",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [0.6143,1.64,0.9208,1.64,0.9208,1.7193,0.6143,1.7193],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": "Terms",
   "words": [
    {"boundingBox": [0.6143,1.64,0.9208,1.64,0.9208,1.7193,0.6143,1.7193],
     "text": "Terms",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.6318,3.2388,1.6318,3.2388,1.7385,2.3861,1.7385],
   "appearance": {
    "style": {
     "name": "other",
     "confidence": 1
    }
   },
   "text": ": Due on Receipt",
   "words": [
    {
     "boundingBox": [2.3861,1.6588,2.4067,1.6588,2.4067,1.7194,2.3861,1.7194],
     "text": ":",
     "confidence": 1
    },
    {
     "boundingBox": [
      2.4456,
```

1.6392,
2.6437,
1.6392,
2.6437,
1.7195,
2.4456,
1.7195
],
"text": "Due",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.6803,
1.6572,
2.8008,
1.6572,
2.8008,
1.7195,
2.6803,
1.7195
],
"text": "on",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.8435,
1.6318,
3.2388,
1.6318,
3.2388,
1.7385,
2.8435,
1.7385
],
"text": "Receipt",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.622,
1.7913,
1.0807,
1.7913,
1.0807,
1.8714,
0.622,
1.8714
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Due Date",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.622,
1.7913,
0.8114,
1.7913,
0.8114,
1.8714,
0.622,
1.8714
],
"text": "Due",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.8525,
1.7913,
1.0807,
1.7913,
1.0807,
1.8714,
0.8525,
1.8714
],
"text": "Date",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.3861,
1.7819,
3.0196,
1.7819,
3.0196,
1.8906,
2.3861,
1.8906
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": ": 28/08/2021",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
2.3861,
1.8109,
2.4067,
1.8109,
2.4067,
1.8715,
2.3861,
1.8715
],
"text": ":",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.4406,
1.7819,
3.0196,
1.7819,
3.0196,
1.8906,
2.4406,
1.8906
],
"text": "28/08/2021",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6214,
2.0441,
0.9464,
2.0441,
0.9464,
2.133,
0.6214,
2.133
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Bill To",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6214,
2.0441,
0.7876,
2.0441,
0.7876,
2.1325,
0.6214,
2.1325
],
"text": "Bill",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.8181,
2.0535,
0.9464,
2.0535,
0.9464,
2.133,
0.8181,
2.133
],
"text": "To",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.62,
2.255,
1.0775,
2.255,
1.0775,
2.355,
0.62,
2.355
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Md Riaz",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.62,
2.255,
0.7914,
2.255,
0.7914,
2.355,
0.62,
2.355
],
"text": "Md",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.8401,
2.2563,
1.0775,
2.2563,
1.0775,
2.3547,
0.8401,
2.3547
],
"text": "Riaz",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.7076,
2.5806,
0.773,
2.5806,
0.773,
2.6586,
0.7076,
2.6586
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "#",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.7076,
2.5806,
0.773,
2.5806,
0.773,
2.6586,
0.7076,
2.6586
],
"text": "#",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.0119,
2.5724,
1.988,
2.5724,
1.988,
2.679,
1.0119,
2.679
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Item & Description",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
1.0119,
2.5806,
1.2406,
2.5806,
1.2406,
2.6601,
1.0119,
2.6601
],
"text": "Item",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.2784,
2.5787,
1.3516,
2.5787,
1.3516,
2.6595,
1.2784,
2.6595
],
"text": "&",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.3882,
2.5724,
1.988,
2.5724,
1.988,
2.679,
1.3882,
2.679
],
"text": "Description",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.8379,
2.5787,
6.0289,
2.5787,
6.0289,
2.6794,
5.8379,
2.6794
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Qty",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
5.8379,
2.5787,
6.0289,
2.5787,
6.0289,
2.6794,
5.8379,
2.6794
],
"text": "Qty",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.5922,
2.5797,
6.8278,
2.5797,
6.8278,
2.6601,
6.5922,
2.6601
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Rate",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
6.5922,
2.5797,
6.8278,
2.5797,
6.8278,
2.6601,
6.5922,
2.6601
],
"text": "Rate",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3646,
2.5806,
7.7832,
2.5806,
7.7832,
2.6601,
7.3646,
2.6601
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Amount",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3646,
2.5806,
7.7832,
2.5806,
7.7832,
2.6601,
7.3646,
2.6601
],
"text": "Amount",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.7192,
2.7535,
0.7498,
2.7535,
0.7498,
2.8315,
0.7192,
2.8315
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.7192,
2.7535,
0.7498,
2.7535,
0.7498,
2.8315,
0.7192,
2.8315
],
"text": "1",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.9831,
2.7516,
1.7297,
2.7516,
1.7297,
2.8331,
0.9831,
2.8331
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "APPSeConnect",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.9831,
2.7516,
1.7297,
2.7516,
1.7297,
2.8331,
0.9831,
2.8331
],
"text": "APPSeConnect",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.8463,
2.7516,
6.0455,
2.7516,
6.0455,
2.8331,
5.8463,
2.8331
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
5.8463,
2.7516,
6.0455,
2.7516,
6.0455,
2.8331,
5.8463,
2.8331
],
"text": "1.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.4338,
2.7516,
6.8481,
2.7516,
6.8481,
2.8491,
6.4338,
2.8491
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1,000.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
6.4338,
2.7516,
6.8481,
2.7516,
6.8481,
2.8491,
6.4338,
2.8491
],
"text": "1,000.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3874,
2.7516,
7.8017,
2.7516,
7.8017,
2.8491,
7.3874,
2.8491
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1,000.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3874,
2.7516,
7.8017,
2.7516,
7.8017,
2.8491,
7.3874,
2.8491
],
"text": "1,000.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.9909,
2.8715,
2.341,
2.8715,
2.341,
2.9801,
0.9909,
2.9801
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "(28-08-2021 to 27-08-2022)",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.9909,
2.8715,
1.5636,
2.8715,
1.5636,
2.9801,
0.9909,
2.9801
],
"text": "(28-08-2021",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.6191,
2.883,
1.7153,
2.883,
1.7153,
2.9611,
1.6191,
2.9611
],
"text": "to",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.7528,
2.8715,
2.341,
2.8715,
2.341,
2.9801,
1.7528,
2.9801
],
"text": "27-08-2022)",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.9984,
2.8817,
6.029,
2.8817,
6.029,
2.9597,
5.9984,
2.9597
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
5.9984,
2.8817,
6.029,
2.8817,
6.029,
2.9597,
5.9984,
2.9597
],
"text": "1",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.0235,
3.0681,
6.4919,
3.0681,
6.4919,
3.1571,
6.0235,
3.1571
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Sub Total",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
6.0235,
3.0681,
6.2023,
3.0681,
6.2023,
3.1571,
6.0235,
3.1571
],
"text": "Sub",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.2354,
3.0681,
6.4919,
3.0681,
6.4919,
3.1569,
6.2354,
3.1569
],
"text": "Total",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3666,
3.0757,
7.7808,
3.0757,
7.7808,
3.1731,
7.3666,
3.1731
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1,000.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.3666,
3.0757,
7.7808,
3.0757,
7.7808,
3.1731,
7.3666,
3.1731
],
"text": "1,000.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6351,
3.1723,
1.3611,
3.1723,
1.3611,
3.2611,
0.6351,
3.2611
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Total In Words",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6351,
3.1723,
0.8917,
3.1723,
0.8917,
3.2611,
0.6351,
3.2611
],
"text": "Total",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.9295,
3.1817,
1.0053,
3.1817,
1.0053,
3.2597,
0.9295,
3.2597
],
"text": "In",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.0423,
3.1723,
1.3611,
3.1723,
1.3611,
3.2611,
1.0423,
3.2611
],
"text": "Words",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6422,
3.3003,
2.095,
3.3003,
2.095,
3.4082,
0.6422,
3.4082
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Rupees One Thousand Only",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6422,
3.3089,
1.0316,
3.3089,
1.0316,
3.4082,
0.6422,
3.4082
],
"text": "Rupees",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.0551,
3.3079,
1.2756,
3.3079,
1.2756,
3.3892,
1.0551,
3.3892
],
"text": "One",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.2965,
3.3003,
1.8189,
3.3003,
1.8189,
3.3892,
1.2965,
3.3892
],
"text": "Thousand",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.84,
3.3003,
2.095,
3.3003,
2.095,
3.4082,
1.84,
3.4082
],
"text": "Only",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.2158,
3.2378,
6.4932,
3.2378,
6.4932,
3.3267,
6.2158,
3.3267
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Total",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
6.2158,
3.2378,
6.4932,
3.2378,
6.4932,
3.3267,
6.2158,
3.3267
],
"text": "Total",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.2074,
3.2454,
7.7826,
3.2454,
7.7826,
3.3433,
7.2074,
3.3433
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Rs.1,000.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.2074,
3.2454,
7.7826,
3.2454,
7.7826,
3.3433,
7.2074,
3.3433
],
"text": "Rs.1,000.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.7647,
3.4133,
6.4887,
3.4133,
6.4887,
3.5134,
5.7647,
3.5134
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Balance Due",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
5.7647,
3.4133,
6.22,
3.4133,
6.22,
3.5134,
5.7647,
3.5134
],
"text": "Balance",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.2656,
3.4229,
6.4887,
3.4229,
6.4887,
3.5134,
6.2656,
3.5134
],
"text": "Due",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.1339,
3.4218,
7.7819,
3.4218,
7.7819,
3.5321,
7.1339,
3.5321
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Rs.1,000.00",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.1339,
3.4218,
7.7819,
3.4218,
7.7819,
3.5321,
7.1339,
3.5321
],
"text": "Rs.1,000.00",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6351,
3.7124,
1.8961,
3.7124,
1.8961,
3.8206,
0.6351,
3.8206
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Thanks for your business.",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
0.6351,
3.7124,
0.9841,
3.7124,
0.9841,
3.8011,
0.6351,
3.8011
],
"text": "Thanks",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.023,
3.7124,
1.1641,
3.7124,
1.1641,
3.8012,
1.023,
3.8012
],
"text": "for",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.1911,
3.7398,
1.4169,
3.7398,
1.4169,
3.8206,
1.1911,
3.8206
],
"text": "your",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
1.4525,
3.7124,
1.8961,
3.7124,
1.8961,
3.8012,
1.4525,
3.8012
],
"text": "business.",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.7353,
4.4857,
6.8014,
4.4857,
6.8014,
4.5939,
5.7353,
4.5939
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "Authorized Signature",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
5.7353,
4.4857,
6.2869,
4.4857,
6.2869,
4.5745,
5.7353,
4.5745
],
"text": "Authorized",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
6.325,
4.4903,
6.8014,
4.4903,
6.8014,
4.5939,
6.325,
4.5939
],
"text": "Signature",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.5798,
11.1207,
5.8183,
11.1207,
5.8183,
11.2264,
2.5798,
11.2264
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "This is a sample document generated for testing purposes only",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
2.5798,
11.1207,
2.7874,
11.1207,
2.7874,
11.2075,
2.5798,
11.2075
],
"text": "This",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.8238,
11.1219,
2.8972,
11.1219,
2.8972,
11.2075,
2.8238,
11.2075
],
"text": "is",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
2.9315,
11.1467,
2.9805,
11.1467,
2.9805,
11.2072,
2.9315,
11.2072
],
"text": "a",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
3.0178,
11.1207,
3.3775,
11.1207,
3.3775,
11.226,
3.0178,
11.226
],
"text": "sample",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
3.4132,
11.1207,
3.9228,
11.1207,
3.9228,
11.2075,
3.4132,
11.2075
],
"text": "document",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
3.9569,
11.1207,
4.4816,
11.1207,
4.4816,
11.2264,
3.9569,
11.2264
],
"text": "generated",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
4.5228,
11.1207,
4.6713,
11.1207,
4.6713,
11.2075,
4.5228,
11.2075
],
"text": "for",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
4.7054,
11.1219,
5.0623,
11.1219,
5.0623,
11.2264,
4.7054,
11.2264
],
"text": "testing",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.1034,
11.1467,
5.5659,
11.1467,
5.5659,
11.226,
5.1034,
11.226
],
"text": "purposes",
"confidence": 1
},
{
"boundingBox": [
5.6012,
11.1207,
5.8183,
11.1207,
5.8183,
11.226,
5.6012,
11.226
],
"text": "only",
"confidence": 1
}
]
},
{
"boundingBox": [
7.7572,
11.4777,
7.7802,
11.4777,
7.7802,
11.5362,
7.7572,
11.5362
],
"appearance": {
"style": {
"name": "other",
"confidence": 1
}
},
"text": "1",
"words": [
{
"boundingBox": [
7.7572,
11.4777,
7.7802,
11.4777,
7.7802,
11.5362,
7.7572,
11.5362
],
"text": "1",
"confidence": 1
}
]
}
]
}

Answer (score 2):

There is a brand new online portal provided by Microsoft https://preview.vision.azure.com/demo/OCR

The advantage is that it will directly list your available resources so you just have to pick the right one, then you test, and there are also some samples.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some clue in the result object which might give you some insights about the lines.

The boundingBox present for each row gives you the co-ordinates of each Text Element in the PDF. What you need to do, is to match the Y axis points, this will give you the exact line which you can map for related data.

For example, in your JSON,

From 20th Element, you see the bounding Box element's 2nd parameter, which is the first y point gives you boundingBox 2.7516.
Now if you see all the next elements on the same line, it will give you same point in 2nd parameter.

I think  you need to create a Generic method which can loop through these boundingBox to get you the related data in a line.